# htaccess com url amigável não está funcionando(?)

Tags: htaccess, url

Eu estou terminando um projeto, e pensei em colocar uma URL amigável, uma que eu já tinha usado em outro projeto, a mesma coisa, não mudei nada, apenas o server e host do site.

De: `www.site.com/noticia?id=1` para `www.site.com/noticia/1`
porém, ele está adicionando um "/" no final de tudo (`www.site.com/noticia/1/`), o que está dando a página "NOT FOUND".

No outro projeto que mencionei acima, ele está igual, mesmo código, só mudei as informações que vai buscar e retornar da página que exibi o conteúdo, porém o último "/" está dando o conflito, e não faço ideia de como retirar isso.

Procurei em vários sites para ver se acha alguma forma de retirar ou até mesmo outro que fazia a mesma coisa, porém, sem sucesso, procurei aqui também e nada.

Eu só não sei se a host tem alguma influência nisso, já que eu não costumo mexer muito com o .htaccess.

No wamp ele roda corretamente, mesmo sem o .htaccess, porém, na host da esse problema.

O .htaccess está assim

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1.php/$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 403 //403.php
ErrorDocument 404 //404.php
ErrorDocument 500 //500.php
```

O Código da página de exibição:

```
<?php 
include_once "assets/inc/head.php"; 
include_once "assets/inc/busca.php";
$Carro =  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$CarroN = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$CarroL = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$CarroF = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$muda_path = explode('/', $Carro );
$muda_path = explode('/', $CarroN );
$muda_path = explode('/', $CarroL );
foreach($muda_path as $carro_link){
    $CarroID = $carro_link;
    $CarroNome = $carro_link;
    $Carro_Link = $carro_link;
    $video_select = "SELECT * FROM carros WHERE `id`='$CarroID' OR `link_carro`='$Carro_Link' OR `nome_carro`='$CarroNome'";
    $query = @mysql_query($video_select) or die (mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0) {
    $vd = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    include_once "assets/inc/not_found.php";
    };?>
```

Eu ainda sou meio novo na programação já que mexo mais com html e css, então, o código pode estar meio amador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu costumo utilizar o seguinte

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^noticia(|/)$ noticia.php
RewriteRule ^noticia/(.*)$ noticia.php?id=$1
```

Utilizo em meu host e nunca me apresentou problemas.

Comment: valeu @VME, parece que deu certo, retirou a última barra, mas agora descobri também o arquivo não está pegando o `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` do link sem o `.php` da 'noticia'. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já resolvi o problema, apenas mudei para `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` e agora funcionou. Valeu pela ajuda!!

Comment: Opa. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido. Só pude entrar agora.
Se puder dar um upvote, ficaria feliz!

Comment: sou novo no Stack, e não tenho reputação suficiente ://